# python-ValueError: unconverted data remains: (UTC)

Tags: python

I have a problem converting rfc2822 date to datetime object
Here's my code

```
from datetime import datetime

messages = {(m["subj"].upper(),datetime.strptime(m["date"],"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")) for m in messages}
```

And here's the error

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  (UTC)
```

Message data structure:

```
{
    "subj": "к20 7",
    "date": "Sun, 14 Feb 2021 22:10:59 +0300"
}
```

Comment: This example works fine. I guess date format in json isn't unified.

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. Thanks